# C++ Outputting text every x times

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that sorts magic the gathering cards, and I'm attempting to output text every x times, where x is specified by user. For example, the program counts down from 100, but only displays integers every 5 steps.

so the output would be
100
95
90
85
80
75
and so on.

I was trying to use an if statement for this, but I can't get my head around it. I'm new to programming, and I'm self taught, which is probably the root of my problems.

Comment: [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

`if ((x % 5) == 0)` will trigger whenever x is divisible by 5 without a remainder. `%` refers to the following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 100; i >= 0; i -= x)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Comment: @Odedra It answers the question as I understand it.  The question seems pretty clear to me.  To critique or request clarification on an answer leave a comment below their answer.